# How to make a POST request to OpsGenie?

Tags: c#, .net, curl

I'm trying to make an API call work to create an alert but I am not sure how to do it properly. It doesn't make a lot of sense to me so I supplied the code below that I wrote but can't work out why it's returning a Bad Request error.

It could be that my request is incorrectly formatted or something but I can't tell as I've never done anything to do with CURL before.

It's supposed to post a curl request that looks similar to:

```
curl -XPOST 'https://api.opsgenie.com/v1/json/alert' -d '
{
     "apiKey": "eb243592-faa2-4ba2-a551q-1afdf565c889",
      "message" : "WebServer3 is down",
      "teams" : ["operations", "developers"]
 }'
```

But it doesn't work.

Call to function:

```
OpsGenie.createAlert("1b9ccd31-966a-47be-92f2-ea589afbca8e", "Testing", null, null, new string[] { "ops_team" }, null, null);
```

At the end, it returns a bad request. I don't know if there's something wrong with how I'm putting in data or anything so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void createAlert(string api, string message, string description, string entity, string[] teams, string user, string[] tags)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://api.opsgenie.com/v1/json/alert"));
        string json = "{";
        if (api != null)
            json = json + "'apiKey': '" + api + "'";
        if (message != null)
            json = json + ", 'message': '" + message + "'";
        if (description != null)
            json = json + ", 'description': '" + description + "'";
        if (entity != null)
            json = json + ", 'entity': '" + entity + "'";
        if (teams != null)
        {
            json = json + ", 'teams': '['" + string.Join(",", teams) + "']'";
        }
        if (user != null)
            json = json + ", 'user': '" + user + "'";
        if (tags != null)
            json = json + ", 'tags': '" + tags.ToString() + "'";
        json = json + "}";
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        request.Method = "POST";
        try
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }


            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream: httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
                var messageFromServer = obj.error.message;
                Console.WriteLine(messageFromServer);

            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to use `WebClient` for a task like this. It has a number of helper methods that make downloading and uploading content like strings really easy.

Also, instead of trying to build the JSON payload by concatenating strings, just use Newtonsoft.Json.

I refactored your method to use `WebClient` and `JsonConvert`. It's a lot simpler now! I left the debugging in place, but you can remove the console logging lines after you've tested it:

```
public static void CreateAlert(string api, string message, string description, string entity, string[] teams,
    string user, string[] tags)
{
    // Serialize the data to JSON
    var postData = new
    {
        apiKey = api,
        message,
        teams
    };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);

    // Set up a client
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

    try
    {
        var response = client.UploadString("https://api.opsgenie.com/v1/json/alert", json);
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        using (var stream = wex.Response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            // OpsGenie returns JSON responses for errors
            var deserializedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(reader.ReadToEnd());
            Console.WriteLine(deserializedResponse["error"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For making `POST` requests, make sure you are using the **Team API key**, instead of the **User API key**.

You can find the Team API key in the following path:

```
https://your_domain_name.app.opsgenie.com/teams/
```

- Click on team; if there is no team, create one.
- Click on the newly created team, and select *Integrations*. (You will get an API key.)

As I can see your URL is `https://app.opsgenie.com` (Us-region); if you're using the European region, then the URL should be `https://api.eu.opsgenie.com`.

Comment: This worked for me , I think this information is not shared anywhere. Thanks . Can you please explain I have Global API access key with all rights and other I have TEAM API key , why I am able to create alerts with TEAM API KEY but not with GLOBAL one ?

Answer (score 0):

Since API v1 is now deprecated, the above solution should look like:

```
public static void CreateAlert(string api, string message,
string description, string entity, string[] teams,string user, string[] tags)
{
 // Serialize the data to JSON
    var postData = new
    {
        apiKey = api,
        message,
        teams
    };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);

    // Set up a client
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    client.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"GenieKey {api}");
    try
    {
        var response = client.UploadString("https://api.opsgenie.com/v2/alerts", json);
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        using (var stream = wex.Response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            // OpsGenie returns JSON responses for errors
            var deserializedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(reader.ReadToEnd());
            Console.WriteLine(deserializedResponse["error"]);
        }
    }
}
```